# How to send container logs to journald when using containerd CRI

Tags: kubernetes, logging, containerd, systemd-journald, container-runtime-interface

So far we have been collecting logs from our Kubernetes containers on node level from systemd-journald in a containerd+Dockershim environment.
But now we are migrating to away from Dockershim and I cant find a setting which tells containerd to send container logs to journald instead of `/var/log/containers`.

The following sources make me feel it should be possible but I dont understand how to put in practice:

- [github.com/containerd/containerd/runtime/v2/README.md#logging](https://github.com/containerd/containerd/blob/main/runtime/v2/README.md#logging)
- [github.com/containerd/log](https://github.com/containerd/log)

I tryied running containerd with the default config and looked for refenreces online but couldn't find any. Currently the container log files are created under `/var/log/containers` and just containerd systemd service logs are send to journald.

It there a containerd config setting I should put in place?
Or alternatively, how to set up a log plugin?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.